# C# PowerShell - setting local Windows 10 account usernames and passwords after receiving input

Tags: c#, powershell

I wrote a console application in C# that generates a password according to a pattern - it is now simply stored within a String variable "result".

How do I go about setting a local user with that password?
I have seen that it can be done with PowerShell - but how do I invoke PowerShell within a C# console app?

I chose C# because it is a very easy language for me and I didn't know that you could do so much in PowerShell (functions, arrays, everything that I need) should I have scripted everything within PowerShell?

Comment: Not sure how possible it is as I do not think C# was meant to interface that way with the OS; this might help as it is calling PS from C# https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kebab/2014/04/28/executing-powershell-scripts-from-c/

Comment: Thanks for the comment - I will check it out... but the more I look at it, the more I see that it would be a big security issue if that was possible.

Answer (score 0):

Later version of powershell include the `new-localuser` cmdlet that lets you create windows users.  You would have to convert the password to a SecureString but https://google.com can help you with that.

Creating a user is not a security exposure.  I doubt you'll find any Windows API that lets you decode passwords so I wouldn't worry about that.

You will need to find a way to secure the password because you will presumably need to communicate it to whoever needs to use it to use the account.

I would try to avoid calling PowerShell from C#.  Anything you can do in powershell you can do in native code so to me you would either use the C# / .net OR you would use Powershell.

If you feel compelled to use C# from within powershell there's a way to embed a simple class as include text and PS will compile it into your script.  But I've found PS powerful enough that I don't even consider doing that for anything any more.